# CkEditor showing black triangles after build in Angular?

Tags: angular, build, ckeditor, text-editor

I have installed the following module
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic

In the module where I need to integrate ckeditor I add that in the module and the use in the ts and HTML file

in Module

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular'; 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CKEditorModule //here module added
  ],
})
```

in the TS file

```
import { CkeditorConfig } from '../../../shared/ckeditor-config';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

editor = ClassicEditor;config=CkeditorConfig;
```

in HTML

```
<div class="mb-24">
              <ckeditor [editor]="editor" rows="6" [config]="config" formControlName="Answer" [data]=""></ckeditor>
              <mat-error class="cus-err" *ngIf="faqForm.get('Answer').touched && faqForm.get('Answer').hasError('required')">
                  Answer is required
              </mat-error>
            </div>
```

In the localhost, everything works fine [image]
no error at all options that I have defined is working well

In the server, it shows some black triangles also[image]

In the server, it shows some error also[image]

Also whenever I enter a new line it shows one more black triangle
If someone faces the issue, please let me know so I can rectify the issue.
Hope I explain everything

Comment: I have just the same problem. But ckeditor5-build-classic is working correctly in my case. And when I'm trying to build custom editor from the stable repo, even with no modifications, I am getting the same giant black triangles. It seems like the table plugin is somehow broken. 
I even tried to build editor from "CKEditor 5 online builder" (classic), but it results in completely empty toolbar.

Comment: so how you got work

Comment: @vladimirkhozeyev so do you know any way how to remove that in server builds as I got this only in the builds but not in the localhost(ng serve)

Comment: Sorry i stopped fixing it. We decided to remove CKEditor, upgrade to angular 9 and use Quill editor (it had issuies on angular 8).

Comment: so quill worked fine

Comment: Yeah, quill is working fine under angular 9, but it breaks prod build under angular 8.

Comment: really appreciated for that, will check other option or move to quill under 9 version

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Angular.json file and change the optimization property from true to false

This should sort out your problem.